# Как очистить jtable и заполнить её другими данными?

Tags: jdbc, java, swing

Я вывожу результат запроса в jTable, используя DefaultTableModel, но после этого мне нужно полностью очистить jTable и вывести в неё результат совершенно другого запроса, у которого будет другое количество столбцов и их содержимое.
Так вот, как произвести эту самую очистку?

Comment: код может покажеш?

Answer (score 1):

в цикле`tableModel.removeRow(i);`.
а еще есть метод `rowsRemoved(TableModelEvent e)`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?